# Given a proper field extension $L/K$, can we have $L\cong K$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, ring-isomorphism

Given a proper field extension $L/K$ (that is, $K$ can be considered as a *proper* sub-field of $L$).
Can it still happen that $K\cong L$ via a field-isomorphism? I assume *No*, but I am utterly illiterate in basic field theory, so if this is really easy, then I would already be happy with a hint in the right direction.

Comment: Check Luroth theorem. If $K$ is any field and $x$ any indeterminate then any field $L$ with $K\subset L\subseteq K(x) $ is isomorphic to $K(x) $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you can take $K$ to be a function field on countably many indeterminates, and get $L$ by adding one more indeterminate.